# auto-pst-pdf: Not working properly with rotations >=45°

Tags: graphics, pdftex, auto-pst-pdf

I'm using `psfrag` to replace text in .eps-figures. Since I'm working also with other graphic formats I use `pdflatex` and therefore the package `auto-pst-pdf`. Everything worked quite well so far. Today I tried to rotate a picture with an angle of 90° and I noticed that this works only for angles <= 45°. If the angle exceeds 45°, e.g. 60°, the figure is printed with an angle of -30° which is (60-90)°.

LaTeX example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage[on]{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
  \centering
  \psfragfig[angle=60]{test.eps}
\end{figure}

end{document}
```

Thus, 90° results in 0°, 100°->10°, 134°->46°. BUT 135°->135° (?!) and then 136°=->-44°=(136-180)° and so on.

It seems that `auto-pst-pdf` does not pass the argument of the option `angle` correctly to the `includegraphics`-command.

Does anybody has an idea what's the reason for this and how a rotation of 90° can be achieved?

Comment: In my version of auto-pst-pdf the options of `\psfragfig` are passed to `\includegraphics`. `angle` can't get loss. But perhaps `ps2pdf` does some autorotating. Do you have the same problem is you use a picture without text e.g. tiger.eps from CTAN? (add the option `width=8cm`).

Comment: The problem depends indeed on text. I've tried it with the tiger and I've also drawn a simple rectangle. One version with, the other without text. Without text everything works fine. Adding the text, the explained effects occur.

Comment: If you are on windows you could try `\expandafter\def\expandafter\autorotatenone\expandafter{\detokenize{-dAutoRotatePages#/None}}` and then `\usepackage[on,ps2pdf=\autorotatenone]{auto-pst-pdf}`

Comment: Yes, I'am on Windows but unfortunately that did not help, nothing changed.

Comment: Could you put one of the problematic eps somewhere for download?

Comment: I've uploaded the rectangle example here: [link](http://www.speedshare.org/download.php?id=26A4718C1)

Comment: Well the option is actually called `pspdf` and not `ps2pdf` but correcting this error doesn't help ;-(. The missing `-dAutoRotat‌ePages#/None` is the source of the problem. But I can't find a way to insert this option in the `ps2pdf` call. While `ps2pdf  -dAutoRotatePages#/None example.ps` works without problem I always get an `/undefinedfilename in (ePages#/None)` error as soon as I use it inside a `\write18`. I will to think about it again tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I think I solved it. I had a problem with an invisible unicode char in my utf8-encoded files which truncated the argument. Life was easier when we all used 8bit-encodings. The following worked for me. There is perhaps a simpler way to hide the hash, but I don't have time now. (I used crop=off as I have currently a problem with pdfcrop).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begingroup
\catcode`\#=11
\gdef\autorotatonone{-dAutoRotatePages#/None}
\endgroup

\usepackage[crop=off,pspdf={\autorotatonone}]{auto-pst-pdf}


\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}%
        \includegraphics[angle=60]{test.eps}%
\end{postscript}

\begin{postscript}
        \includegraphics[angle=60]{test_text.eps}%
\end{postscript}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I honestly don't understand what you did, but it works without any complaint. By the way, I don't have any problems if I skip `crop=off`. Thx for your time and the effort you made. So did I get that right, when text is present `ps2pdf` does some autorotating because `auto-pst-pdf` does not pass the option correctly? In that case we might inform Will Robertson, the author of `auto-pst-pdf`.

Comment: On windows auto-pst-pdf doesn't use the option on purpose - perhaps because Will didn't get around the problem how to pass the #, or because he didn't know that you should replace the = used on linux with an #. It would certainly a good idea to inform him.

Comment: I've written him an email. So that should it be so far.